# How to use a dependency that I imported with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I added this dependency to my project so I could use the `WebClient` class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I ran `mvn clean install -U` and it download the dependency successfully. Then I closed IntelliJ and opened it again. The IDE recognized the dependency smoothly. However, I can't figure out how to actually use it in my code...

If I do: `WebClient webClient = new WebClient();` it just complains that it `cannot resolve symbol "WebClient"`, it doesn't suggest me to import it. I tried importing manually with `import org.springframework.boot.*;`, but still doesn't recognize the symbol. Any tips on how I fix this?

**module-info.java**

```java
module org.openjfx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;

    opens agill.deshopp to javafx.fxml;
    opens agill.deshopp.controllers to javafx.fxml;
    opens agill.deshopp.components to javafx.fxml;

    exports agill.deshopp;
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>agill.deshopp</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.32.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>agill.deshopp.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You can use `mvn verify` should do that same. `install` is not necessary. The `-U` usually isn't necessary either.

Comment: Either the class `WebClient` is not available in the library or you need to import the class.

Comment: Hm... I tried `mvn verify` but it didn't work either. Apparently the class should be available, I'm following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient) tutorial. I'm almost sure this is a problem with my project setup, since the same thing happened when I tried to import another lib.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the synchronise button in maven plugin on right hand side in intellij. The first Button you can see in picture.
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQG7M.png

Comment: I don't have that plugin :(
The plugins available at my Maven window are: clean, compiler, deploy, install, jar, resources, site and surefire.

Comment: Edited the post and added picture. Click the first button in image under Maven Heading

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it didn't change anything. I guess what this does is downloading the dependencies, right? But it seems to me that's not the problem. Anyway, thank your for your effort.